# Using Map and reduce with a problem in clojure

Tags: clojure

The question I need to answer is
“Define a function called sum-of-squares that takes one collection of numbers as a parameter. The function should use map and reduce to compute the sum of the squares of the input numbers.”

The code I used was

```
(defn square [x] (* x x))

(defn sum-of-squares [x] 
  (map square(reduce * x)))
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question -- can you reword it so it's clear what you are actually asking? You've shown some code but you need to add what it produces and what you are trying to produce for some concrete collections of numbers. Also, it sounds like you're asking us to do your homework...?

Comment: @SeanCorfield The goal seems pretty clear to me from the problem statement. I don't see how concrete examples would make it any clearer. Sure, it's asked a little clumsily, but the only "problem" I see with this is that it's clearly a homework problem. And those are allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a concrete example to develop the function.

```clj
;;; First we define a particular vector of numbers as an example.
user> (def nums [0 1 2 3 4 5])
#'user/nums
;;; Then we define the square function as you did.
user> (defn square [x] (* x x))
#'user/square
;;; Now map the square function across nums to get a sequence of squares
user> (def squares (map square nums))
#'user/squares
user> squares
(0 1 4 9 16 25)
;;; Now define a function that adds all the numbers
user> (defn add-all [c] (reduce + 0 c))
#'user/add-all
;;; Use add-all to add up the squares.
user> (def result (add-all squares))
#'user/result
;;; Check that the result is what was desired.
user> result
55
;; Put together the map and the add-all to get the sum-of-squares.
user> (defn sum-of-squares [ns]
        (reduce + 0 (map square ns)))
#'user/sum-of-squares
;;; Verify that you get the same answer as before.
user> (sum-of-squares nums)
55
user>
```

Comment: No need to pass `0` to `reduce` when using `+`.

Comment: True.  I find it good practice to always include the initial value, whether it is required or not.

Comment: How is that good practice? Now `reduce` iterates an additional time when it doesn't need to, no matter how expensive whatever it does is. Waste of time and resources.

Comment: From the point-of-view of a computer, I agree that it is an extra iteration.

Comment: From the programmer point-of-view, using the initial value makes it explicit what the initial value is. It also makes it consistent for thinking about the reducing function.  If you do specify the initial value, then all reducing functions behave the same way for all values of the sequence.  If you do not specify an initial value, then the reducing function needs to be aware that the first time around, it is called differently than any other time.

Comment: From the programmer pov it still sucks because now you have to write more code than you otherwise would have. And when you don't know what the initial value should be (for `+` and `*` it's easy but for other fns it might not be, and for unknown fns you just can't know) you'd have to do `(reduce + (first some-list) (rest some-list)`. That's unnecessary and gross. Consumers of `reduce` should just know how it works. And the reducing function should be written to work for arbitrary lengths of input anyway.

Comment: Generically, a reducing function is of the form `(fn [acc e] ...)` where `acc` is the accumulated result so far, `e` is the current element of the collection being processed, and the result of the function is the next value of the accumulated result.  If you provide an initial value to `reduce` it is tantamount to specifying the initial value of the accumulator.

Comment: In addition, if you specify the initial value, you only need a 2-arity function for the accumulator.  If you do NOT specify the initial value to `reduce` you have to provide a reducing function with a 2-arity AND a 0-arity (to handle the case when the collection has no elements).

Comment: For what it's worth, Rich Hickey himself has said that the arity of `reduce` without an initial value was probably a mistake on his part and it's why he has recommended that folks who create reducible things implement `IReduceInit` only (and not `IReduce`). See this transcript of his talk about transducers: https://github.com/matthiasn/talk-transcripts/blob/master/Hickey_Rich/InsideTransducers-mostly-text.md

Answer (score 0):

Try to translate each line into a code one at a time.

1. Take a collection. (range function returns a collection)

```
(range 10)
```

2. Map each element into its square form. Threading operator helps.

```
(->> (range 10)
     (map #(* % %)))
```

3. Sum it using reduce.

```
(->> (range 10)
     (map #(* % %))
     (reduce +))
```

4. Wrap it into a function.

```
(defn sum-of-squares [n]
(->> (map #(* % %) n)
     (reduce +)))
```

Answer (score 0):

> compute the sum of the squares of the input numbers

That phrase is practically your answer.  All you need to do is break it down into code:

```
(sum (squares inputs))
```

Now all we need to do is figure out how to express `sum` and `squares`.  For `sum`, we can use `reduce` and `+`:

```
(defn sum [coll]
  (reduce + coll))
```

`squares` is just a `map` over a function that computes the square of it's input.  The `square` function given in the question works just fine for this:

```
(defn squares [coll]
  (map square coll))
```

Or, if you prefer a one-liner:

```
(reduce + (map square inputs))
```

If you compare this to the code in your question, it's pretty close.  The only things you missed were:

1. You want to `map` first, then run the output through `reduce`.  This means the `map` (or at least the result it produces) should be inside the `reduce`, not the other way around.  Also, `reduce` in this case produces a single value, not a collection.  And passing a single value in lieu of a collection to `map` will result in an error.
2. You want to *sum* the squares, not multiply the squares together.  So we should pass `+`, not `*`, to `reduce`.